# How to avoid circular dependency here

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have two tables; to make the example easy, let's call them `lawnmower` and `lawn`.

- The lawnmower is always mowing a lawn.
- Multiple lawnmowers can be mowing the same lawn.
- A lawn has a single lawnmower which is responsible for that lawn.
- A lawnmower can however be responsible for 3 lawns at the same
  time.

The intuitive solution:

- Let lawnmower reference the lawn it is mowing
- Let lawn reference the responsible lawnmower

This gives a circular dependency. What is the best solution to avoid this? I'm currently considering a `responsiblefor` table with foreign keys to a lawn and a lawnmower. This however enables multiple lawnmowers to be responsible for the same lawn, which was not possible before.

Comment: OOP concerns with circular dependencies don't apply to databases.  There's nothing wrong with your intuitive solution.

Comment: Intuitively it would be impossible as well. Either can't exist without the other. I would never be able to create my first lawn or lawnmower because they need each other to exist.

Comment: That's what transactions are for.

Comment: I then arrive at the question: Is that good design, when it is avoidable?

Comment: To enforce integrity, you would still need to use transactions with any other design.  It's a good design if it allows only valid data to be recorded while being easy to manipulate and query.  In this case, I believe it compares well against other designs.  Avoiding non-issues don't factor into it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want a junction table because this is fundamentally an n-m relationship.  This table would have one row per lawnmower and per lawn (I would called it `LawnmowerLawns` or something like that).

Now to handle the bullet points:

- The first one requires a row in this table for every lawnmower.  This can be handled with a trigger in most databases.  There are probably other solutions as well.
- The second is handled by the junction table.
- The third is handled by having a flag in the table to represent the "primary" lawnmower for each lawn.  This can be enforced via a trigger or other mechanisms.
- The fourth requires a trigger (counts on a relationship usually require triggers).

Comment: Sounds like I am on the right track. Only difference is, I kept the reference to the lawn being mowed with the lawnmower, only using the junction table to map responsibility. Is there any argument to including it into the junction table?

Comment: Since we're dealing with two distinct predicates (`lawnmower mows lawn` and `lawnmower is responsible for lawn`), I would recommend two separate relationship tables.  That allows us to use the PK or a unique key to enforce the relationship cardinalities.